# How can I tell which ethernet port is the one connected with an ethernet cable?

Tags: centos, networking

This system's was basically cloned from another system so it has its network properties so the network does not work at all. I connected an ethernet cable into one of the ethernet ports and ran ifconfig. I think the output is giving me the details of the previous system. I can't connect to the internet at all or ping other systems on the same network. I ran

```
$lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
```

and the output gave me the two ethernet ports I believe

```
00:1f:6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0e7c
00:00:0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 13g7 (rev 02)
```

so the ethernet ports are detected. How do I determine which port is being connected by the ethernet cable? I'm not sure if virbr0 is actually one of the ethernet ports or if it is from the previous original system.

EDIT

I just ran lshw -class network and it list the 2 networks and I'm sure its both of them because one has a bus info ending with pci@0000:00:1f.6 which is what one of the ethernet controllers outputs from the lspci command was "00.1f.6". It list both networks as "UNCLAIMED" aboe the two other networks virbr0-NIC which list as DISABLED and virbr0 so my problem is those two are unclaimed right now.

EDIT2

this is what the lshw -class network looks like when using ubuntu off a usb stick which detects the ethernet ports

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eno2
       version: 02
       serial: **:**:**:**:**:**
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:a4200000-a42fffff memory:a4300000-a4303fff memory:a4100000-a41fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: **:**:**:**:**:**
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 ip=10.134.33.118 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:130 memory:a4600000-a461ffff
```

ANSWER

Ok the issue was that I did not have the proper drivers installed which is why the ethernet controllers were listed as "UNCLAIMED" when I ran the lshw -class network command on the Centos OS.

I got these drivers here after finding out the model of the ethernet controller, I forgot what command I used to find the exact model since running lspci doesn't really provide the right details but basically I just went to this link here and downloaded the appropriate file

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html

The e1000e driver fixed this issue for me and once I loaded the e1000e module, I finally saw the "eno1" device and just created a network config file for it and restarted the Network Manager.

Comment: could you include output of `ip a`?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `ethtool` like this:

```
ethtool --identify enp0s31f6
```

where `enp0s31f6` is one of my NIC showed by `ip a` command. This command enable leds on port physical connection.

Comment: all I get is "Cannot idenitify NIC: Operation not supported" when I run the command for all the devices that are listed when I run nmcli d which returns virbr0,lo,virbr0-nic

Comment: i ran the command and i got the line 00:1f:6 0200: 8086:0d5b which i think is one of the ethernet ports.

Comment: I just ran lshw -class network and it list the 2 networks and I'm sure its both of them because one has a bus info ending with pci@0000:00:1f.6 which is what one of the ethernet controllers outputs from the lspci command was "00.1f.6". It list both networks as "UNCLAIMED" aboe the two other networks virbr0-NIC which list as DISABLED and virbr0 so my problem is those two are unclaimed right now

Comment: hey i am running ubuntu without installing off a usb stick on this same system and it detects the network off the bat. Is there anything I can get from here and transfer over to the centos side? I posted the output of lshw -class network in the edits which shows a different output on the ubuntu side compared to the centos side where the ethernet ports are showing unclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

`ethtool`, as the name implies, only works with Ethernet interfaces, not with `virbr0` and so on. Also, it is unable to distinguish between an interface that is DOWN and an interface without connection, so you also need to check the interface configuration status, for example `ip link`.

Another option is `cat /sys/class/net/enp0s31f6/carrier`. If 1, there is a connection. If 0, there isn't. If an error is returned, the device is DOWN.